# Issues Opening Large DTM File in QGIS - ‘Bad Allocation’, 'Error occurred while parsing element at line 1 column 1' Error

Tags: qgis, dem, large-datasets

I’m trying to open a large DTM  file in QGIS but I’m encountering errors. The data is a DTM 5x5 m map of the Lombardia region. The .ige file is 7.7 GB and the .img file is only 522 KB.

I’ve tried opening the file in both the stable long-term release (version 3.28.13 “Firenze”) and the latest version (3.34.1 “Prizren”) of QGIS. Since im a complete beginner i tried opening both the ige and the img files, just in case. Trying to open the img in both versions i get a ‘bad allocation’ error. Trying to open the ige in both versions I received a parsing error. The exact error message I received is: ‘Unable to open project: Project file read error: error occurred while parsing element at line 1 column 1’.

I’ve already tried re-downloading the file from the official site of Geoportale Lombardia and checking the file path. Despite these efforts, the issue persists.

I’m using a Windows system with a 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13650KF CPU @1.65GHz, 14 cores, 28 logical processors, and 31.7 GB of memory. During the execution of QGIS, only Microsoft Edge, Notepad, and File Explorer are open, and I have 352GB of free disk space.

How can I successfully open this large DTM file in QGIS without encountering these errors?

Comment: The img file contains the headers and other data, the ige has the raster info for it, so keep them together.  Add the img to a project.  Can you download smaller sections of the overall area and add them successfully to a project?  Is your project using the same CRS as the DTM file? Can you contact the data provider to discuss the issue?

Comment: Ive finally been able to solve this, this was an embarassing error from my part due to my absolutely newbie knowledge.
I just had to first create a project and only then try to add it.
Still, thanks for your response